# enable jmxremote on windows

Tags: java, jmx

I'm trying to enable remote monitoring by using jmxremote. When i set the options in a '.bat' file, things are ok (i can connect to the process using JConsole), but fail to do so when i try to do that when the process is ran as a service, although i use the exact properties that i use when the process runs as a '.bat' file (e.g. -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote etc.) can you please let me know what am i missing?

(Please note, the behavior is with and withouth password/access files, with 'authenticate' and 'password' set to true and false).

Thanks

Guy

Answer (score 1):

If you specify *only* `com.sun.management.jmxremote` then the connection will only work as long as the process to be monitored and the monitoring tool run under the same user.

Since services usually run under a system account that's not the case.

You will need to specify a port to listen on to enable connections from other users: [use `com.sun.management.jmxremote. port` for this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevf).